# Preencher Labels com valores de uma tabela do Banco de Dados MySQL

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

**C# e MySQL**

Estou tentando pegar os valores da tabela *Funcionarios* do atual usuário conectado no programa e exibir nos labels do meu form, porém os valores não estão sendo retornados, meu palpite é que a função *dataReader.Read()* não está retornando nada.

Meu código:

```cs
private void FormUsuario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LimparCampos();
            PreencherCampos();
        }

        private void PreencherCampos()
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            Conexao objCon = new Conexao();
            string query = "select * from funcionarios WHERE Nome = '" + f.username + "' AND Senha = '" + f.password + "'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, objCon.Conectar());
            try
            {
                objCon.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dataReader;
                dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read()) 
                {
                    lbl_nome.Text += dataReader.GetString("Nome");
                    lbl_senha.Text += dataReader.GetInt32("Senha");
                    lbl_cargo.Text += dataReader.GetString("Cargo");
                    lbl_cpf.Text += dataReader.GetString("CPF");
                    lbl_telefone.Text += dataReader.GetString("Telefone");
                    lbl_endereco.Text += dataReader.GetString("Endereco");
                    MessageBox.Show("Dados atualizados com sucesso");
                }
                
            }
            catch (MySqlException er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro de conexão: " + er);
            }
            
        }

        private void LimparCampos()
        {
            lbl_nome.Text = string.Empty;
            lbl_senha.Text = string.Empty;
            lbl_cargo.Text = string.Empty;
            lbl_cpf.Text = string.Empty;
            lbl_telefone.Text = string.Empty;
            lbl_endereco.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa o debug e coloca uns breakpoints em nas suas variáveis para ver se primeiro o select está sendo preenchido corretamente